# Problem with ifstream

Tags: c++, file, std

Look at this small code, it open a ifstream :

```
std::ifstream _fcs; 

bool openFile(char* path)
{
    istream::pos_type pos; 
    int tmp = 0;

    _fcs.open(path, fstream::binary | fstream::in);

    if(!_fcs.is_open())
        return false;

    tmp = 0;
    pos = 0x404;

    _fcs.seekg(0x404);
    pos = _fcs.tellg(); /// return zero

    _fcs >> tmp; /// 
    _fcs.read((char*)&tmp, 4);

    return true;
}
```

i have two problems.

1. after seekg, tellg return zero and when I read data it reads from beginning of file.
2. operator >> seems doesn't work. always return zero!

////------------------------------------------------

thanks for your attentions. I found a crazy solution, but I get confused! 
if I call seekg two times, it works, see this code:

```
 bool openFile(char* path)
 {
    istream::pos_type pos; 
    int tmp;
    bool fail;

    _fcs.open(path, fstream::binary | fstream::in);

    if(!_fcs.is_open())
        return false;

    _fcs.seekg(0x402);
    _fcs.seekg(0x402); /// When it comments, the tellg returns 0. am i crazy!?

    fail = _fcs.fail();
    assert(!fail);

    pos = _fcs.tellg(); /// return 0x402!!!

     /// _fcs >> tmp;
    _fcs.read((char*)&tmp, 4);

    return true;
}
```

really, what's happened?
////------------------------------------------------

please help me...
thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Check the failbit using `_fcs.fail()` after your `seekg` call to make sure you haven't specified an invalid file position.

To double check the size use

```
 _fcs.seekg(0,ios::end);
 int length = _fcs.tellg();
```

You also need to use `.read()` to get the len value, as your file is binary

Comment: @Mostafa I'm not sure why you have to call it twice.  You used a different magic number this time (0x402 vs. 0x404), so I'm not sure where in your file that is leading you. I would again check how big the file is and make sure you're not overstepping that size.  When you say it's working, do you mean that you have read the value you are seeking or just that you've moved the file pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In binary mode, >> is not supposed to work, you have to use ostream::write.

Does your file actually exists and have a size ? if note, you can't "move" to an arbitrary point in an empty file.

Comment: yes, it exists. it's a binary file and also i open it with a hex editor. I want to read not write! :(